# Mysql SELECT unicode characters

Tags: mysql, unicode

I have two tables:

`words` table:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | word  | lang |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | uña   | es   |
|  2 | two   | en   |
|  3 | three | en   |
|  4 | four  | en   |
+----+-------+------+
```

`stop_words` table:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | word | lang |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | una  | es   |
|  2 | one  | en   |
+----+------+------+
```

I need to select a word from `words` table where the word are not in `stop_words` table

- If I try the below query the result is empty because `uña` from
  `words` match with `una` from `stop_words`

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM words a WHERE word LIKE  'uñ%' AND lang = 'es'
  AND NOT EXISTS( Select *
      FROM stop_words as b WHERE a.word = b.word AND lang = 'es'
  ```

  )
- If I try to use `BINARY` the result seem to be OK **but fail** if not use same case (ex: `Uñ` instead `uñ` )

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM words a WHERE word LIKE BINARY 'Uñ%'  AND lang = 'es'
  AND NOT EXISTS( Select *
      FROM stop_words as b WHERE BINARY a.word = BINARY b.word AND lang = 'es'
  )
  ```

I use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for database, tables and columns.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why not convert both a.word and b.word into `lower` or `upper` case for comparison, while retaining the `binary`? Something like `BINARY LOWER(a.word) = BINARY LOWER(b.word)`

Comment: I will try that. thank's. I don't know if all those (subquery SELECT + BINARY + LOWER) not repercuting to the performance. Are not another collation that not matching ñ with n ... á with a ... etc ?

Comment: Well, if you don't want collation at all, you could go for `utf8mb4_bin`. If you want to go for a more specific collation, this website has details on what is collated with what, in which sets: http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/. For example, I see there is a utf8_spanish_ci which does not collate n with ñ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, word, lang 
FROM words 
WHERE BINARY word NOT IN (Select BINARY word FROM stop_words);
```

Result :

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | word  | lang |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | uña   | es   |
|  2 | two   | en   |
|  3 | three | en   |
|  4 | four  | en   |
+----+-------+------+
```

using utf8_unicode_ci for tables

**EDIT :**
For the same case

```
SELECT  id, word, lang 
FROM words 
WHERE BINARY LOWER(word) NOT IN (Select BINARY LOWER(word) FROM stop_words);
```

Comment: As @Vasan say above, I will be use that with LOWER(). I am curious if not exist another way more optimized to do the same. thanks

Comment: @MTK If you have access to update the tables 
UPDATE words SET word = LOWER(word)
and make sure when you add new line it is lowercase, if you can't control this add a trigger on the insert.. those my thoughs for the momen